# Why does 'ranges::min/max/minmax' require the iterator to satisfy 'indirectly_copyable_storable'?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I recently noticed that the following code [doesn't work](https://godbolt.org/z/d9EKf5ovK):

```
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << *std::ranges::max(
    std::views::iota(0, 5) |
    std::views::transform([](int i) { return std::make_unique<int>(i); }),
    {},
    std::ranges::iter_move // another spelling of '[](auto&& p) { return *p; }'
  );
}
```

The reason is that the signature of `ranges::max` (the same goes for `rangs::min/minmax`) requires `indirectly_copyable_storable<iterator_t<R>, range_value_t<R>*>`:

```
template<input_range R, class Proj = identity,
         indirect_strict_weak_order<projected<iterator_t<R>, Proj>> Comp = ranges::less>
  requires indirectly_copyable_storable<iterator_t<R>, range_value_t<R>*>
  constexpr range_value_t<R>
    ranges::max(R&& r, Comp comp = {}, Proj proj = {});
```

`indirectly_copyable_storable` is a less well-known concept used to check whether the `value_type` of the iterator can be temporarily stored and reassigned ([[alg.req.ind.copy]](https://eel.is/c++draft/alg.req.ind.copy)):

```
template<class In, class Out>
  concept indirectly_copyable_storable =
    indirectly_copyable<In, Out> &&
    indirectly_writable<Out, iter_value_t<In>&> &&
    indirectly_writable<Out, const iter_value_t<In>&> &&
    indirectly_writable<Out, iter_value_t<In>&&> &&
    indirectly_writable<Out, const iter_value_t<In>&&> &&
    copyable<iter_value_t<In>> &&
    constructible_from<iter_value_t<In>, iter_reference_t<In>> &&
    assignable_from<iter_value_t<In>&, iter_reference_t<In>>;
```

The first four `indirectly_writable` require that `Out` can be written by `value_type` with all four qualifiers (`&`, `const&`, `&&`, `const&&`), where `Out` is the artificial `range_value_t<R>*`, which is `unique_ptr<int>*` in the above example.

Its turns out that this requires the origin range's `value_type` must be copyable, so the constraint is not satisfied.

However, the implementation of `ranges::max` does not seem to require so many restrictions, which can be seen from the implementation of various compilers (taking [MSVC-STL](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/1c59a205787f4fdcd9c20decc8fa6dfa9096d394/stl/inc/xutility#L6834C17-L6841C31) as an example):

```
range_value_t<_Rng> _Found(*_UFirst);
while (++_UFirst != _ULast) {
    if (_STD invoke(_Pred, _STD invoke(_Proj, _Found), _STD invoke(_Proj, *_UFirst))) {
        _Found = *_UFirst;
    }
}
return _Found;
```

We just construct the value and reassign it when the condition is met, that's it. I really don't see the part where we need to do:

```
range_value_t<_Rng>* _Out;
_Out = _Found;
_Out = std::as_const(_Found);
```

In other words, it seems that just check that the last two conditions of `indirectly_copyable_storable` it is enough (the `value_type` may also need to be movable).

So where did the four `indirectly_writable` come from? Why do `ranges::min/max/minmax` all require need such a *complex* `indirectly_copyable_storable`? What are the considerations behind this?

---

<sub>In addition to the `ranges::max` family, the only one that `indirectly_copyable_storable` is used in `<algorithm>` is `ranges::unique_copy`, which specifically for `input_range`. However, this concept still seems overconstrained in terms of its implementation. So maybe the real question is, how exactly does `indirectly_copyable_storable` come out?</sub>

Comment: The "iterator" type here is `range_value_t<R>*` right?

Comment: @T.C. Yes, I clarified the question.

Comment: `&*it` being a stable thing is not required by the library max implementation.  Nor, as far as I can tell, by the max requirement.  Ie, max on an input iterator, where iterators to past elements are not valid.